# Play 2.2.2 with Ebean - Error getting Bean Descriptor when Querying OneToMany

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, ebean

I have the following four models:

**Compatibility:**

```
@Entity
public class Compatibility extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Attribute attr1;

    @ManyToOne
    public Attribute attr2;

    public static Finder<Long, Compatibility> find = new Finder<Long, Compatibility>(
            Long.class, Compatibility.class);


}
```

**Attribute:**

```
@Entity
public class Attribute extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    public String userId;

    @ManyToOne
    public Parameter parameter;

    public static Finder<Long, Attribute> find = new Finder<Long, Attribute>(
            Long.class, Attribute.class);

}
```

**Parameter:**

```
@Entity
public class Parameter extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Problem problem;

    public List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

    public static Finder<Long, Parameter> find = new Finder<Long, Parameter>(
            Long.class, Parameter.class);

}
```

**Problem:**

```
@Entity
public class Problem extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

    public static Finder<Long, Problem> find = new Finder<Long, Problem>(
            Long.class, Problem.class);
}
```

Using Ebean, I'm trying to filter all compatibilities depending on which problem they belong to using this Java Code:

```
List<Compatibility> cs = Ebean.find(Compatibility.class)
                .fetch("attribute").fetch("parameter").fetch("problem").where()
                .eq("problem.id", problemId).findList();
```

Yet I'm causing this error:

```
[RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path problem from models.Compatibility]
```

My guess is that the mapping across several tables is not working. Is there **any** way I can get this done? A manual query perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the problem, but there is no reference between Problem and Compatibility. You should try adding a List attribute to the class Compatibility. Ebean can't know if it have to link between Compatibility.attr1 and Attribute or Compatibility.attr2 and Attribute.

I don't use fetch personally. I find this feature hard to understand and debug (the case you are facing is not unusual). I rather write complex query in sql by hand and retrive the list using this function :

```
/**
 * Function which process a sql query returning a list of object.
 * @param req       the sql query
 * @param classObj  class object of the class to return
 * @return  the list matching the req
 */
public static <T> List<T>   getListFromSql(String req, Class<T> classObj)
{
    List<T>         lst;

    RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder
            .parse(req)
            .create();
    Query<T> query = Ebean.find(classObj);
    query.setRawSql(rawSql);
    lst = query.findList();
    return lst;
}
```